# Break outside loop & invalid syntax error for a python code

Tags: python

I'm having a BREAK OUTSIDE LOOP & INVALID SYNTAX ERROR for a PYTHON CODE

Need help fixing the issue.

The problem is located here at line 43:

```
# taking input for every week
x = int(input("SalesPerson {emp} week {ii}: ".format(emp = employee , ii = i)))
# appending the sales value to the list sales record for further use
sales_record.append(x)
else:
# if no another employee exists, then break the loop
break
```

When I run the code, I get an error at line 43: BREAK OUTSIDE LOOP & INVALID SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: please fix the code formatting. btw, the loop is not included in the code provided, so there is not enough info to provide an answer.

Comment: You need help with your caps lock key. It seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `break` is meant to exit a loop. You are not in a loop when you use the keyword `break`, therefore it is not valid.

See the [Python Language Reference documentation for `break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement).

Without any more details, we can't know what you are hoping to achieve with `break`